# removendo li usando jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

Oi estou fazendo um site responsivo e me deparei com um problema, no layout para desktop entre os menus tem o logo, mas para mobile não tem o logo. Como os menus estão em um li, queria remover o li especifico do logo quando for para mobile e tablet. Tentei usar o window.width() mas não funcionou, então tenteis usar uma função usando o matchMedia mas não deu certo, alguem poderia me ajudar?
Obrigado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagem acima com exemplo do espaço que que fica.

Html:

```
      <nav class="nav">
            <label class="menuMobile">&#9776</label>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><img class="lupa" src="img/lupa.png" alt="Pesquisar" onClick="MostrarCampoPesquisa()"></a>
                  <div id="caixaPesquisa">
                        <form id="formPesquisa" action="" method="get">
                            <input id="pesquisa" type="text" value="" maxlength="150" placeholder="Pesquisar..." onBlur="EsconderCampoPesquisa()">
                        </form>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Página Inicial</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Produtos<img class="flechaVertical" src="img/flecha.png" alt="flecha"></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Aparadores de Livros</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Caixinhas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Chaveiros</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Decoração</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pontos Turísticos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Porta Celulares</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Porta Guardanapos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Porta Retratos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Relógios</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Topos De Bolos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Veículos</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><img id="navLogo" class="navLogo" src="img/logotipo.png" alt="Versatyll"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dúvidas</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.lupa{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    padding-left:35px;  
}

.flechaVertical{
    width:8px;
    height:8px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-top:20px;
    position:absolute;
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);
}

.navLogo{
    width:160px;
    height:90px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.menuMobile{
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    position:fixed;
    margin-left:200px;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:30px;
    padding-top:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:10;
}

.nav{
    width:200px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: fixed;
}

.nav ul{    
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
}

.nav ul li{
    display:block;
    border: #222 1px solid;
}

.nav ul li a,visited{
    color:#000000;
    display:block;
    padding:20px;
    padding-left:45px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #990000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*------------------------------------*/
/* Nav Submenu */

.nav ul li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}

.nav ul ul{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    margin-left:200px;
    margin-top:-200px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    height:550px;
}

.nav ul ul li{
    display:block;
    padding:8px;
}

.nav ul ul li a,visited{
    color:#000000;
    padding:0;
}

.nav ul ul li a:hover{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#990000;
}
```

Jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

RemoveLi();

function RemoveLi(){
    if(window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1023px)').matches){
        $('.nav ul li:nth-child(4)').remove();
    }
}

});
```

Comment: Não estou usando o bootstrap, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

O 'truque' é deixar o elemento com `display:none` quando a tela for pequena. Use `@media-queries` do css para isso:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) { tamanho da tela em que você quer que o elemento seja escondido
     .resli { display:none; }
}
```

Comment: Tentei usar o display:none, mas so a imagem desaparece o espaço fica em branco ao invés de sumir, tentei mudar o height e o width pra 0, e mesmo assim não funcionou

Comment: Tem uma pagina de exemplo para mostrar, assim fica mais fácil te ajudar.

Comment: Aliás voce colocou o display:none no li que envolve a imagem ou somente na imagem.

Answer (score 0):

Se quiser fazer com jQuery:

```
function check_remove_li() {
    if($(window).width() < 1023) {
       $('.nav ul li:nth-child(4)').remove();
    }
}

check_remove_li();
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    check_remove_li();
});
```